# How to prove that the logical and set-theoretic notions of finite quantity coincide.

Tags: first-order-logic

In first-order logic with identity, we can define a notion of "there are $N$ $x$'s such that $Px$" for each natural number $N$, using quantifiers and identity. But in $ZFC$ set theory, there is another way to define that notion, namely, "$\{x:Px\}$ is equinumerous with the Von-Neumann natural number $N$". How does one prove the meta-theorem that these two notions coincide?

Comment: You will have to give the two definitions so we know what you are asking .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, with $N = 2$, the logical formula looks like
$$ P_2(S) \equiv (\exists x)(\exists y)[x \not = y \land x \in S \land y \in S \land (\forall z)[z \in S \to z = x \lor z= y]].
$$

In the case of the von Neumann ordinal $2 = \{0, 1\}$, we can prove in ZFC that $0 \in 2$, $1 \in 2$, and $(\forall z \in 2)[z = 0\lor z = 1]$. This is because $2$ is defined as $1 \cup \{1\}$, $1$ is defined as $0 \cup \{0\}$, and $0$ is defined as $\emptyset$.  So we can prove $P_2(2)$ in ZFC.

Finally, we can prove directly in ZFC that if $P_2(S)$ holds and if $S$ and $T$ have a bijection between them then then $P_2(T)$ holds as well.

The same kind of proof works for any $N$ instead of $2$. Because the number of quantifiers in the logical formula grows with $N$, we have to prove this as an infinite set of theorems in ZFC, one for each $N$.